# Change default shell for Terminator

Tags: command-line, zsh, terminator

I want to change the default shell of Terminator to zsh.
In `/etc/passwd/` I've changed the default shell to `/bin/zsh`.
This settings changes the default shell in LXTerminal (the default terminal on Lubuntu), but not in Terminator. So I tried `chsh -s /bin/zsh`, but that doesn't work either.

The Terminator [documentation](http://software.jessies.org/terminator/faq.html#heading_toc_j_17) says:

> **How do I change my default shell?**
>
> Terminator will always start the shell specified by the SHELL
> environment variable. (It will fall back to /bin/sh if the SHELL
> environment variable isn't set.) You could simply influence
> Terminator's environment, but the best solution is to tell your
> operating system which shell you'd like, and it will ensure that SHELL
> is set correctly for all applications, not just Terminator. See the
> documentation for your operating system for details on how to change
> your default shell.

So I expected my attempts to work, but they don't. How can I change the default shell in Terminator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a reboot Terminater used zsh. I filled in a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/1122031).

Answer (score 30):

## Use `chsh` to change shell

You can use `chsh` to change your default shell. Running this command will ask for complete path of the shell.

You can also run

```
chsh -s <path_to_shell>
```

to change the shell directly.

## Change Terminator Preferences

You can also change the Terminator preferences directly.

- Open Terminator.
- Right Click on Terminator and select *Preferences*.
- Go to *Profiles* > *Command*.
- Check *Run command as login shell*, *Run a custom command instead of my shell*, and type in the address of the shell.

[image]
 - Close the dialog box.

Comment: This changing the profile custom command does not change the shell like a normal login shell would... use tmux or ssh to launch a login shell like `ssh -t ::1 '/bin/sh -l'`

Comment: Write `/bin/zsh`at Custom Command text box

Answer (score 4):

Ancient question, but after fighting with this for a bit:

**tl;dr**: Terminator reads off of the `$SHELL` environment variable. If you're in a graphical X sesson, this variable was set when you logged in, and won't get reset until you log in *again*, even after you run the `chsh`.

If you were to switch to a text terminal and log in there, you'd see that your `chsh` already took effect. Once you exit and log back in, `$SHELL` gets reset to whatever your shell is in `/etc/passwd`.